# global statement does not work as expected and cannot be accessed within a class

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

```
screen = None #is defined outside of any function

def main():

    pygame.init()
    font = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial", 20)

    img_logo = pygame.image.load("gfx\Logo.png")
    img_logo = pygame.transform.smoothscale(img_logo, (30, 30))
    pygame.display.set_icon(img_logo)
    pygame.display.set_caption("Title")
    

    

    global screen # is set as global
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((res)) #this works as intended and displays correctly



    running = True

    load.Menu(screen, res) 

  


    #----MAIN LOOP
    while running:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                Eventhandler.onClick()
  
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:          
                running = False
    pygame.display.update()

class Button:
    global screen
    print(screen) # returns None
    def __init__(self, img, pos, size):
        self.img = img
        self.pos = pos
        self.size = size
```

When I define a instance of the class Button in a seperate file like this:

`button_start = Main.Button("button_start",[200, 550], [230, 100])`

the print(screen) within the class returns `None` which means that it can't access `screen` even though it is declared as global at the beginning of the class. It also seems as if `main()` only used a local instance which doesnt actually change the variable outside of the function. But this would mean that  `global screen` doesn't work.

What did I miss? Is this not how the global statement works? Because from what I read I should be able to change the variable in a global scope even locally within a function, if I use the statement in that function.

Comment: `global screen` is not "in the function" (Button.__init_). Class attributes are evaluated immediately, but not when the first object is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply tracing your program's execution will show you the problem: the body of a class is executed during its definition.  Your flow is to set screen to `None`, define `main`, and define `Body`.  This last definition includes executing `print(screen)`, which is still `None`.

Most of all, *any* use of `global` is a strong indication that your system design is volatile.  Please replace your global use by "properly" passing any needed information into the class -- at least until you understand well *all* of the implications of class and program initialization, and the various interactions (by which time, you will probably have stopped thinking of global.  :-)  ).

Comment: Thank you! I just passed ```screen``` to the class and avoided using global alltogether.